# Trying to add the Paperclip gem to rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paperclip

I'm following a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5W-Y3aROVE) to set the Paperclip gem up on my rails project.

So the steps I've taken so far..

- Installed ImageMagick on Terminal - brew install imagemagick
- Installed the Paperclip gem - gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
- Added the following to my house.rb model file:

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "300x300", thumb: "150x150#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage/.*\Z/

So all in all my house.rb model file now looks like this:

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence: true
validates :price, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
validates :image, presence: true

has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "300x300", thumb: "150x150#" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

At which point I need to add a migration using the migration generator, so I type in rails g migration house image and it isn't creating a timestamped database migration file in the folder and the terminal is returning:

```
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

and a whole bunch of options. In the tutorial it should return something like:

```
create db/migrate/20150205123408_add_attachment_image_to_posts.rb
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here and I'm new to ruby-on-rails so any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: When you run the generator, you have previously run `bundle install` and are inside your rails project directory? The `Usage: rails new APP_PATH` help only appears when not in a Rails root directory.

Comment: Rookie error, I'd done bundle install yes but I wasn't in the right directory. I apologise. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If problem persist, create the migration manually.

```
 create_table "media", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "image_video_file_name"
    t.string   "image_video_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_video_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_video_updated_at"
    t.string   "text", default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id", null: false
  end

  add_index "media", ["user_id"], name: "index_media_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: The problem was due to being in the wrong directory, newbie mistake. Dually noted about the manual migration though. Thank you!